# proof for critical graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph $G=(V,E)$ is said to be critical if for every edge $e$ not in $E$, adding $e$ to $G$ creates a new copy of $K_{10}$.

1. Find a critical graph on $n$ vertices with ${n\choose 2}-{n-8\choose 2}$.
2. Show that if $G$ is a critical graph on $n$ vertices then $|E|\geq {n\choose 2}-{n-8\choose 2}.$ Hint: use Bollobas's theorem.
   The one mentioned here http://uniformlyatrandom.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/a-theorem-of-bollobas/

For the first question I have an idea,
let's build n/10 connected components so they all are $K_{10}$ and remove one edge. this will give us $K_{9}$ in all of them - when we add back the edge we get $K_{10}$.
Between every component - let's between component A and component B. For every vertex in A we'll add 8 edges to B (doesn't matter which as long as they go from A to B).
If we add another edge to go from A to B we'll get an edge from A with the degree 9 (as needed). also we already know each vertex in B had the degree 8 at least. If the edge "hit" a vertex in B with the degree 8 - this new edge will be the 9 - so we got 10 vertices which all of them have the degree 9.

Can't really understand how to infer the amount ${n\choose 2}-{n-8\choose 2}.$
Also can't explain what happens if n modulo 10 isn't 0.
Have no idea how to solve 2.

I think I have a solution.
Take 8 vertices in random and connect them to every other vertex in G.
So you have 8 vertices with the degree n-1. Every other vertex has the degree 8.
Adding one edge will create 2 edges with a degree 9 + the 8 "original" vertices that are connected to them with degree of n-1.
The number of edges in a complete n Graph MINUS the number of edges not in the graph is the answer.

If someone can help with question 2 or tell me why I couldn't add this to "answers" tab

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm still in the early stages of understanding the question. will take me some time to make prograss - kinda new at this.

Comment: You should edit in your thoughts/attempts when you've made some. People around here are usually more happy to help those who've shown some effort. This will also allow potential answerers to know at what mathematical level they should direct their assistance. Welcome to MSE by the way.

Comment: ty :). I'll work on that and edit it later

Comment: That's better. I think you're overthinking part 1. The formula should give you a hint if you recall that a complete graph on $k$ vertices has ${k\choose 2}$ edges. One question: Which Bollobas's Theorem is the hint referring to? He is very prolific.

Comment: I tried to do ${n\choose 2}$ the number of a complete graph minus the edges I haven't added. Can't seem to count them to get ${n-8\choose 2}$. Is there a simpler way then my solution?